# unhandled exception with django and fastcgi

Tags: python, django, apache, fastcgi

We have a Django application running on FastCGI on a Apache server hosted by Bluehost. It has been running smoothly for a long time. Suddenly every page is issuing this message:
Unhandled Exception
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Firefox Web Console says this: 
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

No changes were made by us, but it is likely that either a configuration change was made by Bluehost, or possibly a software change. Their tech support is unhelpful and slow.

I realize this is a long shot, but if anyone has any idea what might cause such an error on a Django server, I would be grateful.

Comment: This question is a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: Since that error gives us no information (intentionally, since it's configured to run in production with DEBUG off), there's not really any way we could diagnose it. Check your logs if you can, and as a last resort, setting DEBUG to True should get you a stack trace in the browser. Though it'll give the whole world the same information should they view it, so be careful about that.